# What exact steps are taken in Kernel#require in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The ruby specification doesn't document the specific steps taken, exactly what algorithm is used to locate and then execute files in MRI Ruby 1.9.3?

I am essentially looking for: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import for Ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, you aren't requiring a *file*, you're requiring a *feature*.

If you feed a full path into the require call, (e.g. `require '/home/users/kerrick/my_lib/utils'`), it will load the `/home/users/kerrick/my_lib/utils.rb` (or `.so`, or `.dll`, or `.bundle`) file.

If you don't specify a full path, Ruby looks in your load path, in the order shown when you run `ruby -e 'puts $:'` in a UNIX prompt.

Also, keep in mind that if you require a something more than once, it'll only load it once.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, not sure if its what you're looking for.

https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/codeloader.rb#L198